# SDL2/C++: I'm confused about centering the viewport in SDL2

Tags: c++, window, sdl, viewport, centering

When trying to center my renderer's viewport, it seems like adding half of the difference between the window-size and viewport-size to the viewport's x and y coords isn't correct. Instead you need to divide this difference by 3? I'm so confused on this and hope someone has some clarification.

The goal is to render a 4:3 viewport on a 16:9 window.

Aside of this, the viewport's aspect ratio starts skewing completely when I resize the window around manually.

```cpp
SDL_Rect windowRect{ };
SDL_GetWindowSize(m_pWindow, &windowRect.w, &windowRect.h);
SDL_Rect newViewport{ };
float aspectRatio{ 4 / 3.f };
if (static_cast<float>(windowRect.w) / windowRect.h >= aspectRatio)
{
    newViewport.h = windowRect.h;
    newViewport.w = windowRect.h * aspectRatio;
    newViewport.x = (windowRect.w - newViewport.w) / 2; // interchange this between 2 and 3
}
else
{
    newViewport.w = windowRect.w;
    newViewport.h = windowRect.w / aspectRatio;
    newViewport.y = (windowRect.h - newViewport.h) / 2; // interchange this between 2 and 3
}
SDL_RenderSetViewport(m_pRenderer, &newViewport);
```

[Result when divided by 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEPHK.png)

[Result when divided by 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzmeS.png)

[Example of skewed viewport after resizing window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsix1.png)

Regarding the funky centering, I tried looking around on the internet on why SDL2 does this, to obviously no avail.

And about the skewing, I tried applying a couple of changes to the calculations and looked if the numbers I got were actually correct, and they were.

I was expecting something to change with these adaptations but all I could do was break it some more or change nothing.

Comment: ¿What are the actual values of `windowRect` and `newViewport`? ¿Does `windowRect` match real window size? ¿Where do you call this code snippet?

Comment: This cope snippet is the content of `CenterViewport()`, which I call when an `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED` happens. This is called correctly, although twice for some reason everytime I resize the window.
`windowRect` and `newViewport` are the correct dimensions at all times, and when I don't center them they retain the correct dimensions in the renderer. But when I move `newViewport.x` to the right for example using the width or height in the calculation, its dimensions skew around.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The piece of code you show, used with a `SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, nullptr)` call, draws the biggest possible 4x3 rectangle centered inside the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet was right, as in it does make the viewport the largest centered 4:3 rectangle that fits the viewport. The problem was in my rendering method, which passed an `SDL_Rect`, filled using `SDL_GetViewport()`, as parameter. Instead you need to pass `NULL` or any kind of value of zero for it to fill the viewport correctly.

#### Correct

```
void RenderViewport() const
{
    SDL_RenderFillRect(m_pRenderer, NULL);
}
```

#### Incorrect

```
void RenderViewport() const
{
    SDL_Rect viewport{};
    SDL_RenderGetViewport(m_pRenderer, &viewport);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(m_pRenderer, &viewport);
}
```